# Ionic issue with node-sass : cannot download binding

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, sass, node-sass

I had an Ionic project for some time. Recently I got an update of Windows 10 (perhaps that caused the issue) and also installed the latest Node - version 10. Today, I did a clean checkout and did `npm install`. To my surprise, I got this error:

> Downloading binary from
>   https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/win32-x64-64_binding.node
>
> Cannot download
>   "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/win32-x64-64_binding.node":

And indeed, this binding does not exist for 4.7.2. Could it be that it was removed?

Ionic version is `3.19.0`.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJS 10 is not supported by node-sass 4.7.2. Downgrade your Node version to 8 if you're working with Ionic.